# python subprocess "mount" does not prompt for password

Tags: python, subprocess

I just learned subprocess.check_call() function today. I intend to use it to replace my os.system command.

Originally, I have my command as such:

```
os.system("mount -t cifs //source/share /mnt/share -o username=user")
```

The command above will prompt for password and it will mount the drive if the password is correct.

However, if I tried:

```
cmd_string="mount -t cifs //source/share /mnt/share -o username=user"

subprocess.check_call(cmd_string.split(" "), shell=True, stdin=sys.stdin)
```

It would not ask for password. Instead, it just print the partitions. It's like invoke "mount" command without parameters.

Any idea how I can use check_call and still receive interactive input from user?

Comment: maybe this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421206/in-python-how-i-do-use-subprocess-instead-of-os-system will help you..

Comment: BTW, it's `check_call`, not `call_check`; now edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *are* invoking `mount` without parameters.  If you specify `shell=True`, `subprocess` expects the entire command including arguments is passed to the shell as one big string.  If you specify `shell=False` (the default if not specified), the command and its arguments are passed as a list of strings, as you have done by using `split`. By mixing the two forms, you are effectively only passing the string `mount` as the command to be executed.   Either remove `shell=True` or remove the `.split(" ")`.  The first choice is usually better unless there is some reason you need shell parsing to be involved, normally something to be avoided.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like my problem. After removing shell=True, I was prompted for password. However, my screen mess up and I can't type the password properly... I had to use "reset" command to reset my terminal window. Any idea?

Comment: Nevermind, I was using Popen to test it. After I switched back to call_check(), it works as expected!

Comment: If you want you can use python's getpass module (`from getpass import getpass`; pwd = getpass() ) to have a "secure" (no echo) password input directly into your program.