# Python 3: Using subprocess Instead Of os.system

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, sys, os.system

I have a string called `variable` and need to do the `subprocess` equivalent of `os.system`. I've tried to find a way to do this but have only found:

```
variable2 = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print variable2.communicate()[0]
```

However, I'm having trouble understanding how to use it. How do I achieve my goal?

Comment: What are the `args` here? In Py3, `print` is a function, not a statement.

Comment: The code block is copy/pasted because I can't find a way of doing what I need myself, hence the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how I do use subprocess instead of os.system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421206/in-python-how-i-do-use-subprocess-instead-of-os-system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation provides equivalents for several old-style sub-process creation functions. `os.system()` is explained [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system).

Comment: Is there an equivalent for os.startfile() also?

Comment: No. `os.startfile()` is a Windows-specific wrapper around the `ShellExecute()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [4]: os.system('uname -a')
Linux diego-workstation 3.0.0-16-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 27 17:44:39 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Out[4]: 0

In [8]: subprocess.call(['uname', '-a'])
Linux diego-workstation 3.0.0-16-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 27 17:44:39 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Out[8]: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `subprocess.call`, `subprocess.check_call` and `subprocess.check_output` functions.  You may need to pass `shell=True` if you are executing a shell command (as would be given to os.system) rather than explicitly specifying the executable and a sequence of arguments.